# Why does a surface term have to vanish for an operator to be Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, boundary-terms

In section $1.10$ of Shankar's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, it is stated that an operator $K$ satisfying $\langle x \vert K \vert x' \rangle = \langle x' \vert K \vert x \rangle ^*$ is not  enough to guarantee that $\langle g \vert K \vert f \rangle = \langle f \vert K \vert g \rangle ^*$, and thus that $K$ is Hermitian. An explicit computation is given when $K = -iD$, in which it is found that the surface term $$ig^*(x) f(x) \bigg\vert_{a}^{b}$$ must vanish for $K$ to be Hermitian. I'm able to follow the derivation, however, I'm still not sure why said surface term has to vanish, since it seems to me I can show that without assuming such thing. Below is a sketch of what I mean:

Writing down $\vert f \rangle$ and $\vert g \rangle$ in my basis,

\begin{align} 
\vert f \rangle &= \int_{a}^{b} dx' \, f(x') \, \vert x' \rangle \, ; \\
\vert g \rangle &= \int_{a}^{b} dx \, g(x) \, \vert x \rangle \, . 
\end{align}

Then we have,
\begin{align} 
\langle g \vert K \vert f \rangle &= \int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b} dx \, dx' \, g^*(x) \, f(x') \, \langle x \vert K \vert x' \rangle \\ 
&= \int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b} dx \, dx' \, g^*(x) \, f(x') \, \langle x' \vert K \vert x \rangle ^* \\ 
&= \left(\int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b} dx \, dx' \, g(x) \, f^*(x') \, \langle x' \vert K \vert x \rangle \right)^*
= \langle f \vert K \vert g \rangle ^*.
\end{align}
I guess my question is the following: is my derivation correct, and if it is, where am I  assuming that such a surface term vanishes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assuming that $\langle x|K|x'\rangle$ is a simple number which can be straightforwardly complex conjugated.  Indeed, if $\langle x|K|x'\rangle = K_{xx'}$ is a $\mathbb C$-number such that $K_{xx'} = K_{x'x}^*$, then it is indeed Hermitian as you have shown (I will not consider the distinction between Hermitian and self-adjoint operators here).

However, this is generally not the case - in particular, we might take your example that that $K = iD$ (with $D$ the differentiation operator).  In that case, $K_{xx'} = i\delta(x-x') \frac{d}{dx}$, and it is by no means obvious how we might take the complex conjugate of such an object.  Inserting that into your calculation above will result in $\langle f|K|g\rangle$ and $\langle g|K|f\rangle$ differing by precisely the surface term you're asking about.

Ultimately this subtlety arises because we are making use of the position basis $|x\rangle$, which (while useful) comes with a host of technical subtleties related to the fact that the generalized position eigenstates are not actually elements of the Hilbert space, and so $|x\rangle$ is not a true basis in the conventional sense.  If we choose a genuine (countable, orthonormal) basis of the Hilbert space $|\phi_i\rangle$, then the fact that $K_{ij} \equiv \langle \phi_i|K|\phi_j\rangle$ satisfies $K_{ij}=K^*_{ji}$ is indeed sufficient to show that $K$ is Hermitian, because all of the $K_{ij}$'s are simply $\mathbb C$-numbers and so
$$|f\rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i |\phi_i\rangle \qquad |g\rangle = \sum_i \beta_i |\phi_i\rangle$$
$$\langle f|K|g\rangle = \sum_i \sum_j \alpha^*_i \beta_j  K_{ij} =\bigg(\sum_i \sum_j \beta_i \alpha_j^* K_{ij}\bigg)^* = \langle g|K|f\rangle^*$$

---

As a concrete example, we might consider the differentiation operator $D$ defined on the ring, corresponding to the Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$ with periodic boundary conditions (as before, I won't concern myself with domain issues).  Noting that $D_{xx'} = \delta(x-x') \frac{d}{dx}$, we observe that there are no $i$'s to flip.  However, in the eigenbasis of the Hamiltonian operator $H:= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ defined with periodic boundary conditions, we have that
$$\phi_n(x) = e^{2\pi i n x}, n\in \mathbb Z$$
$$D_{n,m} = \langle \phi_n|D|\phi_m\rangle = \int_0^1 \mathrm dx \big(e^{2\pi i n x}\big)^*\big(2\pi i m e^{2\pi i m x}\big)$$
$$=2\pi i m \delta_{nm}$$

So we see - even though $D_{xx'} = \delta(x-x') \frac{d}{dx}$ has no visible $i$'s in it, the matrix elements of $D$ in a *proper* basis are $D_{nm} = 2\pi i m \delta_{nm}$, which immediately implies that $D$ is not Hermitian (in fact, $D^\dagger = -D$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it's starting to make sense. I did not consider before that $\langle x \vert K \vert x' \rangle$ is not an element of some complex-valued matrix expressed in the basis. However, I'm still not clear on where exactly the derivation fails when it's not. My guess is that pulling the conjugate out of the integral was not allowed in my case, is that right?

Comment: @weirdmath I'd say the main problem is that you write $\langle x|K|x'\rangle$ on the right-hand side of the integral as though it's a number in its own right, when in fact it should be thought of as an operator which acts on the function $f$.  As I mentioned in my answer, even defining what $\langle x|K|x'\rangle^*$ is supposed to mean is somewhat ambiguous - I know how to conjugate elements of $\mathbb C$ (simply substitute $i\rightarrow -i$), but how do we conjugate an operator? The appropriate generalization is to find the adjoint, but unless the operator [...]

Comment: [...] is a [multiplication operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_operator), the adjoint is **not** obtained merely by flipping the signs of all of the $i$'s.

Comment: @weirdmath I've updated my answer with a concrete example, showing how the factors of $i$ which appear in the proper matrix elements are in some sense "hiding" in the derivative operator.

Comment: The concrete example you gave and me going back to the expression and plugging in the dirac delta helped make me see it, thanks!